# Problems binding Angular custom directive to model

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to get two multiselect widgets to stay in sync, but am only able to get the behaviour going in one direction.

One widget is on the main page, and the other one is in an angular ui-bootstrap modal. Both multiselect widgets are created using a custom directive. Each instance of the directive is bound to a different controller (MainCtrl and ModalCtrl). The "selected" attribute of each instance of the directive is bound to a scoped variable in their respective controller, which is in turn bound to the same getter method in the Model (getSelectedFilters).

If I change the selection on the widget on the main page, the change is reflected in the widget in the modal panel. However, if I change the selection in the modal panel, the change isn't reflected in the widget on the main page even if the Model has been properly updated (the button "Show currently selected" will show the correct selection even though the widget doesn't). I don't understand the difference at all.

Here is a stripped down plnkr illustrating my problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nC5bkGFE4LkYZsaxdjL7?p=preview

I am entirely new to Angular, and would appreciate any input as to why my directive on the main page isn't being updated properly when the data in the model changes.

Comment: When I try your plunker, the update appears to work in both directions. I can't add directly on the main page, but removing elements on the main page is reflected on the modal, and adding in the modal is reflected on the main page.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I let a friend play with it after I posted my question. He corrected my problem. This is my first time using plnkr rather than jfiddle. It's nice to know that updates show automatically without changing the link like jfiddle does! I will post the answer shortly.

Comment: (Version 7 was what I had initially posted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 7 of the plnkr was what I had initially posted.

Basically, calling $apply on $scope.selected whenever the value was changed was not enough to notify the other directive of the change.  I also had to setup a $watch:

```
$scope.$watch('selected', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    select2.val(newVal).select2(options);
});
```

I am now completely unclear as to why the select2 directive in the modal was updating at all without a $watch when I was modifying the select2 directive on the main page. I would love if someone could explain what was going on there! To anyone who might know, go back to version 7 to see what I mean.